# Felix OSGi Servlet/Resource Filter does not filter

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, osgi, apache-felix

I am trying to filter the web resources of the Jetty HTTP server inside OSGi Apache-Felix.

I've registered a filter as a OSGi component in the Framework:

```
@Component(property = { "osgi.http.whiteboard.filter.name=MyFilter",
                        "osgi.http.whiteboard.filter.regex=.*" },
           scope = ServiceScope.PROTOTYPE)
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    ...
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
                         ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) {
       ...
       // some logging
    }
    ...
}
```

When I start the Felix framework, and access resources and servlets via my browser, the `Filter#doFilter(...)` method never gets called.

The resources and servlets have been registered using `org.osgi.service.http.HttpService#registerServlet(...)` and `org.osgi.service.http.HttpService#registerResources(...)`.

I'm sure, the filter gets initialized, since `Filter#init(...)` gets called:

Here the Felix scr info for the component:

```
Component Description:
  Name: org.myCompany.MyFilter
  Implementation Class: org.myCompany.MyFilter
  Default State: enabled
  Activation: delayed
  Configuration Policy: optional
  Activate Method: activate
  Deactivate Method: deactivate
  Modified Method: -
  Configuration Pid: [org.myCompany.MyFilter]
  Services: 
    javax.servlet.Filter
  Service Scope: prototype
  Component Description Properties:
      osgi.http.whiteboard.filter.name = MyFilter
      osgi.http.whiteboard.filter.regex = .*
  Component Configuration:
    ComponentId: 7
    State: active      
    Component Configuration Properties:
        component.id = 7
        component.name = org.myCompany.MyFilter
        osgi.http.whiteboard.filter.name = MyFilter
        osgi.http.whiteboard.filter.regex = .*
```

- Does resource/servlet filtering work within Felix, Jetty and OSGi?
- Did I register the filter properly?

In the meantime, thank you for your attention and participation.

Comment: OSGi provides regex based filtering??  That's not supported in the Servlet Spec.  btw: (regex) `.*` == (servlet) `/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R6 specification is not clear on the interaction between the HttpService et Whiteboard Services. In fact, the update on RFC 0223 says :

> 3.1 Whiteboard Services and Http Service (Bug 2872)
>
> If a Http Whiteboard implementation is also implementing the Http Service, the
>   whiteboard specification does not specify whether the Http contexts
>   for the Http Service are represented as ServletContextHelper services.
>   There is no way for a whiteboard service to be registered in a Http
>   Context of the Http Service. For example adding a servlet filter for
>   all servlets managed by the Http Service is not possible.

The Felix implementation doesn't share HttpContext and ServletContextHelper: You have to register your servlet with the Http Whiteboard in order to use your Filter.

Comment: thanks, the filter works after registering it with Http Whiteboard.